# Scala: abstract classes with anonymous types

Tags: scala, anonymous-inner-class

I am reading "Scala for the Impatient" and in 8.8 they say:

> [..] you can use the abstract keyword to denote a class that cannot be
>   instantiated [..]

```
abstract class Person { val id: Int ; var name: String }
```

And several lines later:

> You can always customize an abstract field by using an anonymous type:

```
val fred = new Person {

  val id = 1729

  var name = "Fred"

}
```

So, they artificially instantiated Person class with the anonymous type. In which situations in the real world one would want to do it?

Comment: In the first edition of "Scala for the impatient", the class `Person` is declared as `abstract class Person { val id: Int ; var name: String }`. You mixed up the statement from 8.9 with a definition from 8.8 that  had a constructor `Person(val name: String)`. These two examples do not work together. Use definition from 8.9.

Comment: I edited it. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

After thinking about my own answer a little bit, I concluded that all it says is essentially just:

> "Anonymous local class instances are poor man's function literals"

Offered a **`+150`** bounty for an answer that helps expand this narrow vision.

---

**TL;DR**

Whenever you want to treat implementations of methods as objects, you can instantiate an anonymous local class that extends an abstract base class, implement the methods, and then pass the created instance around just like any other instance of the base class.

---

**Overview**

This posting discusses five situations in which you might want to instantiate anonymous local classes. The examples progress from very basic to fairly advanced.

1. Simple example with `Runnable`
2. Simple example with plotting 2d-functions
3. A historically important example `Function<X, Y>`
4. An advanced real-world example where the instantiation of anonymous local classes seems unavoidable
5. Brief discussion of the code that you used to introduce your question.

Disclaimer: some of the code is non-idiomatic, because it "reinvents the wheel" and does not hide the instantiation of abstract local classes in lambdas or SingleAbstractMethod-syntax.

---

**Simple introductory example: Runnable**

Suppose that you want to write a method that takes some block of code, and executes it multiple times:

```
def repeat(numTimes: Int, whatToDo: <someCleverType>): Unit = ???
```

Assuming that you want to reinvent everything from scratch, and do not want to use any by-name parameters or interfaces from standard libraries, what do you put in place of `<someCleverType>`? You would have to provide your base class that looks somewhat like this:

```
abstract class MyRunnable {
  def run(): Unit  // abstract method
}
```

Now you can implement your `repeat` method as follows:

```
def repeat(numTimes: Int, r: MyRunnable): Unit = {
  for (i <- 1 to numTimes) {
    r.run()
  }
}
```

Now suppose that you want to use this method to print "Hello, world!" ten times. How do you create the right `MyRunnable`? You could define a class
`HelloWorld` that extends `MyRunnable` and implements the `run` method, but it would only pollute the namespace, because you want to use it only once. Instead, you can instantiate an anonymous class directly:

```
val helloWorld = new MyRunnable {
  def run(): Unit = println("Hello, world!")
}
```

and then pass it to `repeat`:

```
repeat(10, helloWorld)
```

You could even omit the `helloWorld` variable:

```
repeat(10, new MyRunnable {
  def run(): Unit = println("Hello, world!")
})
```

This is a canonical example of why you would want to instantiate anonymous local classes.

---

**Slightly more interesting example: RealFunction**

In the previous example, the `run` took no arguments, it executed the same code every time.

Now I want to modify the example slightly, so that the implemented method takes some parameters.

I will not provide full implementations now, but suppose that you have a function

```
plot(f: RealFunction): Unit = ???
```

that plots a graph of a real function `R -> R`, where `RealFunction` is an abstract class defined as

```
abstract class RealFunction {
  def apply(x: Double): Double
}
```

To plot a parabola, you could now do the following:

```
val xSquare = new RealFunction {
  def apply(x: Double): Double = x * x
}

plot(xSquare)
```

You could even test it separately without `plot`: for example, `p(42)` computes `1764.0`, which is the square of `42`.

---

**General functions `Function[X, Y]`**

The previous example generalizes to arbitrary functions, which can have types `X` and `Y` as domain and codomain. This is arguably the most important example from the historical point of view. Consider the following abstract class:

```
abstract class Function[X, Y] {
  def apply(x: X): Y // abstract method
}
```

It is similar to the `RealFunction`, but instead of fixed `Double`, you now have `X` and `Y`.

Given this interface, you could re-create the `xSquare` function as follows:

```
val xSquare = new Function[Double, Double] {
  def apply(x: Double) = x * x
}
```

Indeed, this example is so important that Scala's standard library is filled with such interfaces `FunctionN[X1,...,XN, Y]` for varying numbers of arguments `N`.

These interfaces get their own concise syntax and are otherwise heavily privileged in the compiler. This creates a "problem" from the point of view of your question, because the instantiation of anonymous classes is usually hidden under special built-in syntactic sugar. In idiomatic Scala, you would usually simply write

```
val xSquare = (x: Double) => x * x
```

instead of

```
val xSquare = new Function[Double, Double] {
  def apply(x: Double) = x * x
}
```

The situation is similar in other JVM languages. For example, even Java version 8 introduced bunch of very similar interfaces in `java.util.function`.
Few years ago, you would have written something like

```
Function<Integer, Integer> f = new Function<Integer, Integer>() {
  public Integer apply(Integer x) {
    return x * x;
  }
};
```

in Java, because there were no lambdas yet, and every time you wanted to pass some kind of callback or `Runnable` or `Function`, you had to implement an anonymous class that extends an abstract class. Nowadays, in newer Java versions it is hidden by the lambdas and the SingleAbstractMethod-syntax, but the principle is still the same: the construction of instances of anonymous classes implementing an interface or extending an abstract class.

---

**An advanced "almost-real-world"-example**

You will not encounter any of the previous examples in the code written today, because the instantiation of anonymous local classes is hidden by syntactic sugar for lambdas. I want to provide a realistic example where the instantiation of anonymous local classes is actually unavoidable.

The `new AbstractClassName(){ }`-syntax still appears where no syntactic sugar is available. For example, because Scala has no syntax for polymorphic lambdas, to construct a natural transformation in a library like Scalaz or Cats, you would usually write something like:

```
val nat = new (Foo ~> Bar) {
  def apply[X](x: Foo[X]): Bar[X] = ???
}
```

Here, `Foo` and `Bar` would be something like embedded domain specific languages that operate on different levels of abstraction, and `Foo` is more high-level, whereas `Bar` is more low-level. It's exactly the same principle again, and such examples are everywhere. Here is an almost "photo-realistic" example of real-world usage: [defining an `(KVStoreA ~> Id)`-interpreter](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/freemonad.html#write-a-compiler-for-your-program). I hope that you can recognize the `new (KVStoreA ~> Id) { def apply(...) ... }` part in there. Unfortunately, the example is fairly advanced, but as I mentioned in the comments, all the simple and frequently used examples have been mostly hidden by lambdas and Single-Abstract-Method syntax over the past decade.

---

**Back to your example**

The code that you quoted

```
abstract class Person(val name: String) {
  def id: Int
}

val fred = new Person {
  val id = 1729
  var name = "Fred"
}
```

does not seem to compile, because the constructor argument is missing.

My guess is that the author wanted to demonstrate that you can override `def`s by `val`s:

```
trait P {
  def name: String
}

val inst = new P {
  val name = "Fred"
}
```

While it's good to know that this is possible, I don't consider this the most important use case for anonymous local class instantiation (because you could have used an ordinary member variable and pass the value in the constructor instead). Given the space constraints, the author of the book probably just wanted to quickly demonstrate the syntax, without going into extended discussions of the real-world usage of that.

Comment: I am new to Scala and therefore I am reading this book. I am very overwhelmed by your explanation. I would want to customise my abstract class with anonymous type when I want to extend an interface by accepting more parameters? Why would I instantiate a val for it and not something else? Could you please give a more concrete example, without super abstract definitions like Foo, Bar, Function?

Comment: @Tonja Hmm, ok, agreed, maybe it's a bit too high-level. The problem is: all the simple and obvious things have been buried under tons of syntactic sugar in the past ten years, even in relatively conservative languages like Java. The real-world usage cases where this remains most relevant (and is not merely a work-around for a bad interface design) are therefore somewhat advanced (like the example from scalaz). I hoped that the `square`-function is concrete enough, but I'll try to rewrite it in a way that the explanation starts with simpler examples.

Comment: @Tonja I've added two more basic examples: a reimplementation of `Runnable` and hopefully very concrete and intuitive `RealFunction` example for plotting 2d-graphs. So, the posting starts from very basic examples, and then progresses to very advanced example from scala cats (just skip that, if you want). Otherwise: just don't worry too much about it. All the frequent usages of this pattern have been mostly incorporated into syntax anyway. It's nice if you can recognize it if you see it, but you probably won't need it too often.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin one related (but not exactly the same) concept is instantiating a trait with at least one method lacking implementation. Quite useful in testing to provide stubs and fakes. If that qualifies the conditions you've set I can expand this comment to be a proper answer with links and code examples.

Comment: @J0HN Yes, if you can explain how it is useful for providing stubs for testing, that would definitely qualify as a non-lambda-like example.

Comment: @J0HN But if you want to bring the example with test frameworks, it would be nice if you could do it in the next 24 hours, otherwise the grace period for the bounty ends...

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Thanks for the heads up - I'll try to allocate some time to it tomorrow (which is in about 10 hours from now - it's pretty late in my timezone already)

Answer (score 2):

> This is my second attempt to answer the same question. In my previous attempt, I could come up only with single-abstract-method examples. I want to correct this shortcoming by providing more examples that require overriding more than one method.

---

Here are a few examples where one might want to override more than one method in an abstract local class, and where the overridden methods are tightly coupled to each other, so that separating them makes almost no sense. I really tried to come up with "irreducible" examples, where there is no way around defining multiple coherent methods.

## Graph-like datastructures

Consider directed graphs defined by:

- Set of nodes
- Set of edges
- A function `source` from edges to nodes
- A function `target` from edges to nodes

If we define the sets of nodes and edges implicitly, we can represent graphs as instances of classes that have two type members and four methods:

```
trait Digraph {
  type E
  type N
  def isNode(n: N): Boolean
  def isEdge(e: E): Boolean
  def source(e: E): N
  def target(e: E): N
}
```

For example, the following defines an infinite graph that looks like the positive part of the real line, glued from unit intervals:

```
val g = new Digraph {
  type E = (Int, Int)
  type N = Int
  def isNode(n: Int) = n >= 0
  def isEdge(e: (Int, Int)) = e._1 >= 0 && e._2 == e._1 + 1
  def source(e: (Int, Int)) = e._1
  def target(e: (Int, Int)) = e._2
}
```

The reason why we usually want to override all the methods at once is that the functions have to satisfy a whole bunch of coherence conditions, such as:

```
* for each `e` in domain of `source` and `target`, `isEdge(e)` must hold
* for each `n` in codomain of `source` and `target`, `isNode(n)` must hold
```

Thus, the most natural way to define such infinite graphs would be through instantiation of local anonymous classes.

**Remark:** If you like general abstract nonsense, you will readily recognize this as a special case of *presheaf* on the tiny category with just two objects and two parallel arrows:

```
   --->
*        *
   --->
```

Thus, the example readily generalizes to all such data structures, not only to graphs. It is the definition of a functor that imposes the coherence requirements on the overridden methods.

## Eliminators for mutually recursive datastructures

Another example: fold-like eliminators for complex mutually recursive structures.

Consider the following abstract syntax of a little language that allows us to write down simple expressions with 2d-vectors and scalars:

```
sealed trait VecExpr
case class VecConst(x: Double, y: Double) extends VecExpr
case class VecAdd(v1: VecExpr, v2: VecExpr) extends VecExpr
case class VecSub(v1: VecExpr, v2: VecExpr) extends VecExpr
case class VecMul(v1: VecExpr, a: ScalarExpr) extends VecExpr

sealed trait ScalarExpr
case class ScalarConst(d: Double) extends ScalarExpr
case class DotProduct(v1: VecExpr, v2: VecExpr) extends ScalarExpr
```

If we attempt to define an interpreter that can evaluate such expression, we quickly notice that there is quite a lot of repetition: essentially, we just keep calling the same mutually recursive `eval`-methods that don't seem to depend on anything but the types. We can hide some of the boilerplate by providing the following base class for interpreters:

```
trait Evaluator[S, V] {
  def vecConst(x: Double, y: Double): V
  def vecAdd(v1: V, v2: V): V
  def vecSub(v1: V, v2: V): V
  def vecMul(v: V, s: S): V

  def scalarConst(x: Double): S
  def dotProduct(v1: V, v2: V): S

  def eval(v: VecExpr): V = v match {
    case VecConst(x, y) => vecConst(x, y)
    case VecAdd(v1, v2) => vecAdd(eval(v1), eval(v2))
    case VecSub(v1, v2) => vecSub(eval(v1), eval(v2))
    case VecMul(v, s) => vecMul(eval(v), eval(s))
  }

  def eval(s: ScalarExpr): S = s match {
    case ScalarConst(d: Double) => scalarConst(d)
    case DotProduct(v1, v2) => dotProduct(eval(v1), eval(v2))
  }
}
```

Now, implementors of the interpreter can work with fully evaluated vectors and scalars directly, without recursive calls. For example, here is an implementation that evaluates everything to doubles and tuples:

```
val ev = new Evaluator[Double, (Double, Double)] {
  def vecConst(x: Double, y: Double) = (x, y)
  def vecAdd(v1: (Double, Double), v2: (Double, Double)): (Double, Double) = (v1._1 + v2._1, v1._2 + v2._2)
  def vecSub(v1: (Double, Double), v2: (Double, Double)): (Double, Double) = (v1._1 - v2._1, v1._2 - v2._2)
  def vecMul(v: (Double, Double), s: Double): (Double, Double) = (v._1 * s, v._2 * s)

  def scalarConst(x: Double): Double = x
  def dotProduct(v1: (Double, Double), v2: (Double, Double)): Double = v1._1 * v2._1 + v1._2 * v2._2
}
```

Here, we had to override half a dozen of methods in a coherent way, and since they are all very tightly coupled, it does not make any sense to represent them by separate `Function`-instances. Here is a little example of this interpreter in action:

```
val expr = VecSub(
  VecConst(5, 5),
  VecMul(
    VecConst(0, 1),
    DotProduct(
      VecSub(
        VecConst(5, 5),
        VecConst(0, 2)
      ),
      VecConst(0, 1)
    )
  )
)

println(ev.eval(expr))
```

This successfully projects the point `(5,5)` on the plane that goes through `(0, 2)` with normal vector `(0, 1)`, and outputs:

```
(5.0,2.0)
```

Here, it seems as if it's the mutual recursion that makes it difficult to disentangle the family of functions, because the interpreter has to function as a whole.

---

So, I'd like to conclude that there definitely are use cases for anonymous local types that go beyond single-abstract-method.

Answer (score 1):

One other example of instantiating an anonymous type is instantiating a trait.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

trait ServiceProvider {
  def toString(int: Int): String
  def fromString(string: String): Int
}

val provider = new ServiceProvider {
  override def toString(int: Int) = int.toString
  override def fromString(string: String): Int = string.toInt
}
// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined trait ServiceProvider
provider: ServiceProvider = $anon$1@33b0687
```

Last line shows that instantiating a trait and instantiating an abstract class have the same outcome - an instance of anonymous local type is created.

This ability comes in handy when in comes to testing - it allows providing stubs and fakes without using any third-party libraries, like Mockito, scalamock etc.

Continuing previous example

```
class Converter(provider: ServiceProvider) {
  def convert(string: String): Int = provider.fromString(string)
  def convert(int: Int): String = provider.toString(int)
}

// somewhere in ConverterSpec
// it("should convert between int and string")
val provider = new ServiceProvider {
  override def toString(int: Int) = int.toString
  override def fromString(string: String): Int = string.toInt
}
val converter = new Converter(provider)
converter.convert("42") shouldBe 42
converter.convert(1024) shouldBe "1024"
converter.convert(converter.convert("42")) shouldBe "42"

// it("should propagate downstream exceptions")
val throwingProvider = new ServiceProvider {
  override def toString(int: Int) = throw new RuntimeException("123")
  override def fromString(string: String): Int = throw new RuntimeException("456")
}
val converter = new Converter(throwingProvider)
a[RuntimeException] shouldBe thrownBy { converter.convert(42) }
a[RuntimeException] shouldBe thrownBy { converter.convert("1024") }
```

The benefits of such approach compared to using some proper stub/mock library are:

1. Easy to provide stateful test doubles
2. Somewhat simpler to use - depends on choice of test double lib - *huge* difference compared to Mockito, not much difference compared to scalamock
3. Somewhat more reliable/maintainable tests - with anonymous instance approach all the abstract members must be implemented + you get compiler to check the implementation against abstract members *added* to the base class/trait, while with stubs no such assistance is available.

There are few drawbacks of course, e.g. anonymous type instance approach can't be used to provide mocks/spies - i.e. test doubles that allow asserting on the calls made to them.

Comment: And this also provides an example of a yet another extremely general pattern: isomorphisms / sections / retractions. It seems very natural to keep the two functions pointing in opposite directions together, and treat them as a unit. So, this actually counts as two examples. Excellent, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There is no real world requirement for using the anonymous class instatiation syntax. You can always create your own class that extends `Person` and then instantiate it once to get the `fred` value.

You can think of this syntax as a shortcut for creating a single instance of a one-off class without having to come up with a name for the class.

It's the same convenience that lambdas (a.k.a. anonymous functions) provide. If you use the function only once, why should we need to define it elsewhere and give it a name, when we can succintly describe it inline?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @RobertoBonvallet! It's of course clear that usage of anonymous local classes is never *strictly necessary*, because one can always declare a one-off class with an explicit name, and then use it only once. But are there any convincing use cases where the anonymous local class syntax is the "lesser evil" compared to all other options? (That is: some convincing examples that are *not* like `F ~> G` in Scalaz)